Why does the exponential I'm trying to calculate go to zero even with double precision?
I'm trying to write a program that calculates the kinetic constant of a reaction using partition functions of thermodynamics. However when trying to compute the exponential the exponent is way too small and it goes to zero, even when using double and quadruple precision.
I don't believe the issue lies with the double precision usage, rather with the exponential itself, that probably has some property I'm not aware of. Other sources just say the exponential is zero and call it a day but I'm supposed to get an actual numerical result.
I attached both the program, the input file I'm using and the output:
INPUT FILE:
298 !temperatura, K
6570 !delta H formazione, J/mol

1 
18.9984  !massa rg1 au
4 ! deg1

2
2.016 !massa rg2 au
4395.2 !vibr, cm-1
0.277 !inerzia au**2
1 !deg

3
linear
21.014 !massa tr au
4007.6 397.9 397.9 310.8  !vibr cm-1
7.433
4 !deg
2 !numero simm

PROGRAM
      program cinetica

c DICHIARAZIONE COSTANTI

      real*8 ktransm, kboltz, rgas, hplanck, AvN, Pst, pi, Vst, c
      real*8 T, deltaf, qpart(3), q, k2
      real*8 part1, part2
      real*16 part3, esp
      common /cost/ ktransm, kboltz, rgas, hplanck, AvN, Pst, pi, Vst, c
      integer atom

      ktransm= 1 !coefficiente trasmissione
      kboltz= 1.38*10**(-23.) !costante di boltzmann, J/K
      rgas= 8.31 ! costante universale dei gas, J/mol*K
      hplanck= 6.62*10**(-34.) !costante di planck, J*s
      AvN= 6.022*10**(23.) ! costante di avogadro, 1/mol
      Pst= 10**(5.) ! pressione standard, Pa
      c= 3.*10**(10.) ! velocità della luce in cm/s
      
C APERTURA FILE E LETTURA DATI
      open(5, file="dati.in")
      open(10, file="cinetica.out")

      read(5,*) T  !temperatura in K
      read(5,*) deltaf  !delta H di formazione in J/mol

      Vst= (rgas*T)/Pst
      pi= 2*asin(1.)

c legge masse con un do e in base al numero di atomi sceglie come calcolare numero di partizione, alla fine produco q di ognuno che assegna a un vettore q con tutte le funzioni
      do 50 i=1,3
        read(5,*) atom    !legge numero di atomi
        write(6,*) atom

        if(atom.eq.1) then
          call monoatomic(T,q)

        elseif(atom.eq.2) then
          call diatomic(T,q)

        else
          call polyatomic(atom,T,q)

        endif

        qpart(i)=q

 50   continue

      write(6,*) "funzioni part", (qpart(n), n=1,3)


C CALCOLO COSTANTE CINETICA (EQUAZIONE DI EYRING) CON FUNZ. PARTIZIONE DA SUBROUTINE E COSTANTI DICHIARATE IN PRECENDENZA
  
c   versione molare, funziona?

c      part1= (ktransm*kboltz*T*Vst)/hplanck
c      part2= (AvN*qpart(3))/(qpart(1)*qpart(2))
c      part3= exp(-deltaf/(rgas*T))
  
c      k2= part1*part2*part3
c      write(6,*) "costante cinetica molare", k2

c   versione molecolare, esponente va a zero

      part1= (kboltz*T)/hplanck
      part2= (qpart(3))/(qpart(1)*qpart(2))
      esp=-deltaf/(kboltz*T)
      part3= exp(esp)

      write(6,*) "esponente e esponenziale", esp, part3

      k2= part1*part2*part3
      write(6,*) "costante cinetica molecolare", k2
      
      stop
      end
c-----------------------------------------------------
C SUBROUTINE MONOATOMICO

      subroutine monoatomic(T,qtot)
      common /cost/ ktransm, kboltz, rgas, hplanck, AvN, Pst, pi, Vst, c
      real*8 ktransm, kboltz, rgas, hplanck, AvN, Pst, pi, Vst, c
      real*8 T, m, deg, qtr, qel, qtot

      read(5,*) m
      read(5,*) deg
      
      write(6,*) m, deg
      m=m*(1.67*10**(-27.))
      qtr= ((2*pi*m*kboltz*T)/(hplanck**(2.)))**(3./2.)*Vst
      qel=deg

      qtot=qtr*qel
      write(6,*) qtr, qel, qtot


      return
      end



c-------------------------------------------------------------
C SUBROUTINE DIATOMICO
      subroutine diatomic(T,qtot)
      common /cost/ ktransm, kboltz, rgas, hplanck, AvN, Pst, pi, Vst, c
      real*8 ktransm, kboltz, rgas, hplanck, AvN, Pst, pi, Vst, c
      real*8 T, m, v, deg, qtr, qrot, qvib, qel, qtot
      real*8 i

      read(5,*) m
      read(5,*) v
      read(5,*) i
      read(5,*) deg

c conversione unità di misura per massa e inerzia
      m=m*(1.67*10**(-27.))
      i=i*(1.67*10**(-27.))*(1.67*10**(-27.))


      qtr= ((2*pi*m*kboltz*T)/(hplanck**(2.)))**(1.5)*Vst
c      write(6,*) "Vst", Vst
      qrot=(8*pi**(2.)*i*kboltz*T)/(hplanck**(2.))
      qvib=1/(1-exp((-hplanck*c*v)/(kboltz*T)))
      qel=deg
      
      qtot=qtr*qrot*qvib*qel
      write(6,*) qtr, qrot, qvib, qel, qtot

      return
      end


c----------------------------------------------------------------------
C SUBROUTINE POLIATOMICO

      subroutine polyatomic(atom,T,qtot)
      common /cost/ ktransm, kboltz, rgas, hplanck, AvN, Pst, pi, Vst, c
      real*8 ktransm, kboltz, rgas, hplanck, AvN, Pst, pi, Vst, c
      real*8 T, m, v(500), deg, qtr, qtot, qvib, qvib1, qel
      real*8 i
      character*20 geom
      integer modes, symm, atom

      read(5,*) geom

      if(geom.eq."linear") then
         modes=3*atom-5
      elseif(geom.eq."non linear") then
         modes=3*atom-6
      else
         write(6,*) "check input: define geometry (linear/non linear)"
      endif

      read(5,*) m
      read(5,*) (v(n), n=1, modes)
      read(5,*) i
      read(5,*) deg
      read(5,*) symm

c conversione unità di misura per massa e inerzia
      m=m*(1.67*10**(-27.))
      i=i*(1.67*10**(-27.))*(1.67*10**(-27.))

      qtr= ((2*pi*m*kboltz*T)/(hplanck**(2.)))**(3./2.)*Vst
      qrot=(8*pi**(2.)*i*kboltz*T)/(symm*(hplanck**(2.)))
      qel=deg

      qvib=1

      do 60 nn=1, modes

        qvib1=1/(1-exp((-hplanck*c*v(nn))/(kboltz*T)))   !parziale del calcolo vibrazionale
        qvib=qvib*qvib1     !produttoria

 60   continue

      qtot=qtr*qrot*qvib*qel
      write(6,*) qtr, qrot, qvib, qel, qtot

      return
      end

OUTPUT
           1
   18.998400000000000        4.0000000000000000     
   2.0035785894328219E+030   4.0000000000000000        8.0143143577312874E+030
           2
   6.9257471645836213E+028   5.7237652847843724E-007   1.0000000006050396        1.0000000000000000        3.9641351215822116E+022
           3
   2.3307405557255242E+030   7.67955771E-06   1.7660399314814128        4.0000000000000000        1.2644179482433861E+026
 funzioni part   8.0143143577312874E+030   3.9641351215822116E+022   1.2644179482433861E+026
 esponente e esponenziale  -1597607262508866292678656.00000000000         0.00000000000000000000000000000000000      
 costante cinetica molecolare   0.0000000000000000 

I was trying to compute the kinetic constant and the exponential is a fundamental part, when computing the molar version of the equation it works fine, given that the numbers are not that small. The result should be about 1.43e10, from experimental results, for the molecular version but I'm unable to proceed with calculating the exponential.
As it can be seen form the output the real*16 is working as intended.

The first thing I would suggest, is to change your notation to scientific notation for your constants. Eg. 6.62*10**(-34.) should be written as 6.62D-34. The multiplicatoin actually introduces numeric inaccuracies. Also note the usage of D and not E to ensure double precision.

I’ll definitely correct the scientific notation over all the code. The exponent does not actually go to infinity, it’s “just” about -1.5e24, I even tried with a standard calculator that also gives zero when trying to calculate the exponential

-1500000000000000000000000 is not a small number. If you really want to be dealing with exponentials of numbers that sort of size you need to be rethinking your algorithm, not worrying about whether it's double or quadruple precision. Statisticians, for all their numerous flaws, use log-likelihoods a lot, for example.

Ok that’s interesting, I’ll look into these “log-likelihoods” as I’ve never encountered them in my background. Thank you for your time and kind reply

Are you sure that you should be calculating full partition functions directly?  My recollection is that a full partition function would usually be intractable for anything beyond a toy problem, but ratios of partition functions were not only manageable but useful.  I was usually coming at it from the point of view of Monte Carlo simulation.

If esp ≈ -1.5e24 is the correct statement, then you will not be able to calculate part1*part2*esp(esp), you will only be able to calculate only the logarithm, for example, `log(part1) + log(part2) + esp'.
